# Do I have to install `libbitcoin-server` to be able to include `bitcoin.hpp`?

Tags: c++, bitcoin, raspberry-pi2, lib

I am reading the book "Mastering Bitcoin" from Antonopoulos and want to compile an example from that [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449374042). It does not tell which `C++` library needs to be installed for `#include <bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp>` to work.

```
#include <bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Private secret key.
    bc::ec_secret secret;
    bool success = bc::decode_base16(secret,
        "038109007313a5807b2eccc082c8c3fbb988a973cacf1a7df9ce725c31b14776");
    assert(success);
    // Get public key.
    bc::ec_point public_key = bc::secret_to_public_key(secret);
    std::cout << "Public key: " <> bc::encode_hex(public_key) << std::endl;
    
    // Create Bitcoin address.
    // ... further comments
    
    // Compute hash of public key for P2PKH address.
    const bc::short_hash hash = bc::bitcoin_short_hash(public_key);
    
    bc::data_chunk unencoded_address;
    // Reserve 26 bytes
    // ...
    unencoded_address.reseve(25);
    unencoded_address.push_back(0);
    bc::extend_data(unencoded_address, hash);
    bc::append_checksum(unencoded_address);
    assert(unencoded_address.size() == 25);
    const std::string address = bc::encode_base58(unencoded_address);
    
    std::cout << "Address: " << address << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling should be done like this:

```
g++ -o addr addr.cp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbitcoin)
```

Running `./addr` should give output:

```
"Public key: ..."
"Address: ..."
```

Since there have been a lot of changes to the code base it is unclear what to do with the include. The one of the code is not availlable any more.

Comment: Why do you include that? What Bitcoin-related functions do you need? If they are in that library, how else do you propose the program could ever compile/run without having the library installed? This is too broad a question to answer really.

Comment: I can't find that header in any of the relevant repos on github. Which book is it? Does it really not say more about how the header should be acquired?

Comment: The book is: https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Bitcoin-Unlocking-Digital-Cryptocurrencies/dp/1449374042. The code seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed to install was the library `libbitcoin` or more precisely the "Bitcoin Cross-Platform C++ Development Toolkit" `libbitcoin-system`.

But since the best way to solve this was to use the automatic installation script for debian from [here](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system#debianubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config git
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/version3/install.sh
$ chmod +x install.sh
$ ./install.sh --prefix=/home/me/myprefix --build-boost --disable-shared
```

and this installed the whole `libbitcoin` system with all dependencies e.g. `boost` and `secp256k1` it also installed `libbitcoin-server`.

Installing just parts of it as suggested in another answer did not work for me because of missing dependencies which I could not link properly.

---

Regarding the `swap` I can say that it worked fine with 4GB swapfile on external HDD although the RPi2 has just 20MB/s effective bandwith.

---

To be able to use the library I had to give the `--static` attribute when compiling my program:

```
g++ -o addr 69_addr2.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs --static libbitcoin)
```

Comment: Hi, i when i am compiling example program like this

`
#include <bitcoin/system.hpp>
int main() {
    bc::ec_secret decoded;
    bc::decode_base16(decoded, "038109007313a5807b2eccc082c8c3fbb988a973cacf1a7df9ce725c31b");}
`

i am getting error like  `undefined reference to `libbitcoin::config::checkpoint::checkpoint`. Has the syntax of libbitcoin changed, or i am doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Commit [83f36c901a3f45e8ab667f1db283d72e75a58176](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/commit/83f36c901a3f45e8ab667f1db283d72e75a58176) of the libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system repository renamed `bitcoin/bitcoin.hpp` to `bitcoin/system.hpp`.

It looks like you can just [install](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system#autotools-advanced-users) it with the typical `./autogen.sh && configure && make && make install` steps. After that you can either create a copy of `bitcoin/system.hpp` or adapt your client code.

Comment: Thanks, I am relatively new to this. Is https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system something else than `libbitcoin-server`? I am a bit confused since both have the same parent but different install advices.

Comment: libbitcoin-server depends on libbitcoin-system. If you only need that header file (and whatever code it comes with), you should be able to get by with just libbitcoin-system.

Comment: I just realized that despite having different git sites both actually have identical installation advice and refer to the same `wget` source. Now I have to figure out why it is crashing my Raspberry. :)

Comment: Presumably that is to help people install the full set of libraries. I linked you to the 'autotool for advanced users' section, which is for just installing the -system library.

Comment: A lot of upvotes for this answer but my question is still negative. I appreciate any input on how to improve the question. At the moment, I am not allowed to ask more questions, also because the negative vote here. Thanks!